# Does the SQL Select WHERE statement, test every row or just selecting directly?

Tags: php, sql

I have seen a lot of cms systems, putting all information in the same database table, meaning a lot of rows in the table.

I was then thinking, that when performing an "SELECT FROM database WHERE something" will only pick the right rows, or actually test every row, if it matches the condition?

Comment: How can you select something without comparing it to a standard?

Comment: depends upon a number of things depending upon which database you are using. Indexing would be the main consideration.

Comment: The WHERE statement will filter all the records in that table and only return the matched records.

Comment: How would you be able to only pick the right rows if you don't test all the rows?

Comment: @Jerodev thats exactly what an index allows.

Comment: @Jerodev by using the statistics on your indexes

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: The manuals speak for themselves http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html --- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html

Comment: SQL is not a procedural language.  A SQL query *describes* the result set to be produced, not how it is produced.  A `WHERE` clause does not necessarily test every row.  For example, the table may be partitioned or have indexes defined on it, and these could be used to optimize the `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: @AlexK., true but still it will perform a index key lookup after key scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon whether the used column is indexed or not. The best way to check such concept is use `EXPLAIN` on a query.

> When you issue a query, the MySQL Query Optimizer tries to devise an
>   optimal plan for query execution. You can see information about the
>   plan by prefixing the query with EXPLAIN. EXPLAIN is one of the most
>   powerful tools at your disposal for understanding and optimizing
>   troublesome MySQL queries

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table WHERE COLUMN = 'some value';
```